# Google Authentication using OAuth asks for consumer key,callback URL,Oauth_nonce,signature and version

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth

Google Authentication using OAuth asks for consumer key,callback URL,Oauth_nonce,signature and version.May anyone of you please help me how to find all this details.I have registered my application and I can see the web application as well, but for using OAuth I am helpless.So please help.

Thanks and Regards
Rakesh

Answer (score 2):

If you have registered your application you will have been provisioned with a consumer key (and secret). The oauth_version should be 1.0. Depending on what Google supports and what specification you want to follow it could also be 2.0 (does not seem like it in your case though).

When it comes to nonce, signature and callback, these need to be generated by your application while authenticating your application, and while making API calls.

I suggest you check out what OAuth libraries are available for GAE (I don't know if you are running Java or Python, but there are solutions already out there for you). It is very likely that you will have to understand at least a little bit about OAuth to be able to continue smoothly. And for this reason I suggest you spend some time reading [the tutorial at hueniverse.com](http://hueniverse.com/oauth/guide/).

[Twitter has a nice intro to OAuth 1.0 too](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth#oauth).

**Update**:

I see now that you mention authentication, which is separate from authorization (which is OAuth's primary objective). So if your question concerns logging in users via their Google accounts then there are much simpler solutions.

If you are using Python then check this: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/.
If you are using Java then this: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/

Comment: Hello Jon, I am using Java and I want to use open id for authentication and oauth for authorization, but when I followed the steps said in the URL (http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/openid.html), I have got a page with Login and Logout which no longer redirects to the google login page.